# Using a class from another file in a class (not main) gives undeclared error

Tags: c++

I have a main.cpp file and two class, each class with a .h file and a .cpp file. 
Main.cpp include each class' .h file and use the clases with no problem.
I can get one class to use the other class.

I have tried including the .h file of one class in another but got already declared error.

I have tried declaring the class inside the other class but get incomplete declaration error.

I have spend over an hour reading other stack overflow answer and other sites but nothing I found was the same thing (most of them was problem with main and one class).

main.cpp has:

```
//other includes
#include "class1.h"
#include "class2.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    Class1 classOne; 
    //code that use classOne and works
    Class2 classTwo;
    //code that tries to use classTwo
}
```

class1.h

```
class Class1
{
    //some things
}
```

class1.cpp is irrelevant since everything in it works when used from main.cpp

class2.h

```
class Class2
{
    Class1 classInside; //"does not name a type" error
public:
    void DoSomething(Class1* getClass); //"has not been declared" error
    void DoSomethingElse();
}
```

class2.cpp

```
#include "class2.h"

Class2::DoSomethingElse()
{
    Class1 classOneInsideWorkAlready; //"has not been declared" error
}
```

tried many ways to use class1 in class2 but none worked.

In my project I trying to create an instance of class1, use it in main, then create an instance of class2 (until here everything works) and call methods inside of the instance of class2 to modify the instance of class1 (by using public methods defined inside class1).

Class2 is a part of the program that would be throw away as soon as the user want to use another part (Class3), so no need to keep it in memory.
Class1 tkaes care of what the user see, so I don't want it to disappear when the user change from Class2 to Class3.

Hope that makes some sense and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

To make this particular example work, you need to include the definition of `Class1` into class2.cpp. So far you have only brought it in to main.cpp.

```
#include "class1.h"
#include "class2.h"

Class2::DoSomethingElse()
{
    Class1 classOneInsideWorkAlready; // compiles fine.
}
```

Generally speaking, since `Class2` directly includes an instance of `Class1`, you need to make its definition available to the definition of `Class2`. So including "class1.h" into "class2.h" right in the beginning seems the right way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Adding #include "class1.h" into class2.cpp does make the errors in class2.ccp disappear.
Adding #include "class1.h" into class2.h gives "Redefinition of" error.

Comment: @WorstISPEver The "redefinition of" error is happening because you don't have include guards in your headers. Add "#pragma once" to each in the beginning - the second variant should build fine. The error is because you include the header twice into main, on its own and through class2.h.